# Meta Query - Select the SELECT expression as a string field

Tags: postgresql

Sorry, not sure i am in the right place for this question, but anyway:

I was wondering if there is way in PostgreSQL or any other dbms to select the select statement itself? Smthn like this:

SELECT *, $QUERY_EXPRESSION FROM MYTABLE

?

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't clear; what do you expect as the output of this sample query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it from pg_stat_activity.  To keep it clean, define a function so that the query against pg_stat_activity doesn't iself dominate the text of the query.

```
create function query_text() returns text language sql as $$ 
    select query from pg_stat_activity where pid=pg_backend_pid() 
$$;

select *, query_text() from (values (1),(2)) foo;
 column1 |                    query_text                     
---------+---------------------------------------------------
       1 | select *, query_text() from (values (1),(2)) foo;
       2 | select *, query_text() from (values (1),(2)) foo;
```

Comment: i tried to use in inside func also, but it returns null, but thanks it works nice with a raw query

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `current_query` function:

```
SELECT *, current_query() FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS n;

 n  |                        current_query                        
----+-------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | SELECT *, current_query() FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS n;
  2 | SELECT *, current_query() FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS n;
  3 | SELECT *, current_query() FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS n;
  4 | SELECT *, current_query() FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS n;
  5 | SELECT *, current_query() FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS n;
  6 | SELECT *, current_query() FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS n;
  7 | SELECT *, current_query() FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS n;
  8 | SELECT *, current_query() FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS n;
  9 | SELECT *, current_query() FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS n;
 10 | SELECT *, current_query() FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS n;
(10 rows)
```

Comment: ty, exactly what i failed to google)

Comment: while sadly it doesnt work inside function, it will give you outer call of function instead of select inside the function

Comment: Yes, `current_query()` gives you the *top level query*. There is no way to get nested queries without writing a C function.